# select row having one kind of value only while missing other from a pair

Tags: mysql, sql

I have to select row which has one kind of value in one row but not the other row, both row having a `key` entity common

Sample model :

```
+------+---------+---------------+
| key  | status  |   arrival_p   |
+------+---------+---------------+
|  k1  | failure |      came     |
|  k1  | success |      gone     |
|  k2  | failure |      came     |
|  k3  | success |      came     |
|  k3  | failure |      gone     |
|  k4  | success |      came     |
|  k5  | success |      came     |
|  k2  | success |      gone     |
|  k6  | success |      gone     |
+------+---------+---------------+
```

so in this case, except for `k4` and `k5`, all have come and gone. how can i find folks who have come but not gone?? 
`k6` has just gone, so its an outlier, good to catch it but not immediate priority.

i tried below query but it doesn't work (i know of exact value in actual table which matches my description but below query returns no value at all) :

```
select ap1.`key`
from `arrival_pattern` ap1
    left join `arrival_pattern` ap2
    on ap1.`key` = ap2.`key`
where ap2.`key` is NULL
    and ap1.`arrival_p` = 'came'
    and ap2.`arrival_p` = 'gone'
limit 10;
```

any help or pointers in right direction as to what might be wrong in my join is helpful. i am on mysql.

TIA :)

Comment: Possible values for `arrival_p` are exclusively `came` and `gone`? For each key there's at most 1 record with arrival_p=came and at most 1 record with arrival_p=gone?

Comment: yes sir...its an `enum` from code with only possible values of `came / gone`, `key + arrival_p` have unique constraint

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since both `came` and `gone` can appear only once for a specific key, you might as well select the elements for which a single record exists:

```
SELECT   `key`,
         COUNT(*)
FROM     arrival_pattern
GROUP BY `key`
HAVING   COUNT(*) = 1;
```

This solves also the second question ('k6 has just gone').

Also, note that `key` is a [Reserved Keyword in MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/keywords.html#keywords-8-0-detailed-K). **You should seriously consider naming your column to something else.**

Comment: ohh maannnn....sometimes overthinking kills the simple solution, this is clean +1!!!

Comment: @NoobEditor Also, note that `key` is a Reserved Keyword in MySQL. You should seriously consider naming your column to something else.

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya : this is just a reference schema buddy, dont go by my screen name, m _not_ really that noob! :D

Comment: @NoobEditor ;) well I am not a telepath :P

Comment: If any key just contain 'gone' that key also return on this query  but if your real data is like sample no exception that I thought then it will work fine

Answer (score 1):

use  `not exists`

```
select t1.* from  arrival_pattern t1
where not exists ( select 1 
                   from arrival_pattern t2 
                   where t2.key=t1.key 
                         and t2.arrival_p='gone')
```

you can try below self join

```
select t1.* arrival_pattern t1 
 left join 
(select key from 
  arrival_pattern t2 where arrival_p='gone'
) t2
 on t1.key=t2.key where t2.key is null
```

Comment: any way using `joins`??

Comment: @NoobEditor yes you can use self join

Comment: @NoobEditor actually  EXISTS operator returns true if the subquery returns one or more records so i select constant value 1 rather any column selection you can read docs of sql how exists work